# C multiplexer function

Tags: c, function, logic, circuit

I have this function that's a multiplexer.

```
// Enumerated type for a single bit.
typedef enum { FALSE=0, TRUE=1 } BIT;

BIT multi(BIT A, BIT B, BIT C, BIT D, BIT S1, BIT S0)
{
    if(S1== FALSE && S0 ==FALSE)
        return A;

    else if(S1==FALSE && S0==TRUE)            
        return B;

    else if (S1== TRUE && S0== FALSE)
        return C;

    else
        return D;
}
```

For multiplexer, S1,S0 as a two-bit binary number, indexing into A,B,C,D, in the order given.

so like S1==0 & S0==0 refers to A and S1==0 & S0==1 refers to B etc etc.

I feel my code is close or way off or it is correct I just need to fix how I am testing it in main in which I have...

```
 assert(multiplexer(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) == A);
 assert(multiplexer(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE) == D);
```

Comment: Stylistic comment: the space around the operands of `==` and after `if` is wholly inconsistent in the code.  Code written in a good style is ruthlessly systematic in its layout; spacing is uniform.  On the whole, I'd recommend using `else if (S1 == TRUE && S0 == FALSE)` with a space either side of the `==` operator and a space after `if`.

Comment: I like the idea of: `BIT multi(BIT A, BIT B, BIT C, BIT D, BIT S1, BIT S0) { BIT choice[] = { A, B, C, D }; return choice[(S1 << 1) | S0]; }` for compactness.  I'm not sure where it fits on the scale for speed, but it doesn't have any conditionals which is usually deemed good for speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not *really* well designed tests, those two. Let's look at the first as an example (changing to the *actual* function name of `multi`):

```
assert(multi(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) == A);
```

In this case `multi()` should return the first argument but how would you know if it's returned one of the other three, given that they are *all* false. In addition, I'm not sure whether the `D` variable is even available outside the function so I'm switching to a more specific value.

So a better test set would be:

```
assert(multi(FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE) == FALSE);
assert(multi(TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) == TRUE);
```

That's for testing return of `A`. For `B`, `C` and `D` simply move the unique value to the correct position (2, 3 or 4 respectively) and change what you pass as the selector (positions 5 and 6).

Similarly for the second one, you need to re-write the test so that you can tell the difference between success and failure:

```
assert(multi(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE) == TRUE);
assert(multi(TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) == FALSE);
```

---

As an aside, I'm unsure of the usefulness in creating a special enumeration for a type that C already handles very well on its own (boolean as an `int`).

It appears to me the code could be greatly simplified to:

```
int multi (int r0, int r1, int r2, int r3, int s0, int s1) {
    if (s0) {
        // Must be r2 or r3, depending on s1.
        if (s1) return r3;
        return r2;
    }

    // s0 is false, must be r0 or r1, depending on s1.
    if (s1) return r1;
    return r0;
}
```

Or, once you truly understand C :-)

```
// Returns rX based on sX:
//   s0 false, s1 false, return r0.
//   s0 false, s1 true,  return r1.
//   s0 true,  s1 false, return r2.
//   s0 true,  s1 true,  return r3.

int multi (int r0, int r1, int r2, int r3, int s0, int s1) {
    return ((s0) ? ((s1) ? r3 : r2) : ((s1) ? r1 : r0));
}
```